# What's the longest speech by a sitting US president?

Tags: united-states, president, comparative-politics, rhetoric

[According](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/harrison-dies-of-pneumonia) to History.com

> Ironically, the man with the shortest White House tenure delivered the longest inaugural address in history, which may have been his undoing. This first presidential speech, delivered on a bitterly cold March morning, clocked in at one hour and 45 minutes. Harrison went to bed at the end of inauguration day with a bad cold that soon developed into a fatal case of pneumonia. Some historians have claimed that a case of hepatitis may also have contributed to his demise.

Inaugural addresses aside, are there (other) speeches by a sitting US president longer than that one (1h 45min)?

Comment: This exactly the speach which is known as the longest one by US president.

Comment: So what this question exactly about?

Comment: There's an answer that describes a speech given at a CPAC convention. Are you interested in something like that, or only speeches given as part of the presidential duties, like inaugural addresses, State of the Union, televised/radio addresses to the nation?

Comment: Almost surely longer than the longest speech by a standing U.S. President. ;)

Comment: @Barmar: well, we already have an answer on non-official-capacity speeches. If Harrison's speech is the longest in an official capacity, that would also be interesting to know.

Comment: @Barmar: TBH, I'm not entirely sure such a separation can be made, because inaugural speeches don't seem to be required https://www.archives.gov/milestone-documents/president-george-washingtons-first-inaugural-speech But I suppose one make the distinction still.

Comment: @Fizz While it's not required, it's still related to the office -- no one other than POTUS could make an inaugural address. Compare with Trump's CPAC addresses -- he made them while POTUS and since leaving office, and there's little difference.

Comment: This was defenetly the longest speech by US president: https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/business/podcasts/presidential/pdfs/william-henry-harrison-transcript.pdf

Comment: @ohwilleke Humans can spend up to 8 hours or about slowly walking so long talk is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

President Trump gave a speech to the 2019 Conservative Party Action Committee (CPAC) which lasted 2 hours and 2 minutes - you can watch the whole thing in its entirety [on C-SPAN](https://www.c-span.org/video/?458390-1/president-trump-criticizes-russia-investigation-democrats-hour-long-speech-cpac), if you’re having a slow day. According to the transcript, it contains 16,244 words; almost twice the length of Harrison's speech.

He admitted that he was “completely off script” during the speech, but also argued pithily that “if we don’t go off script, our country’s in big trouble, folks, because we have to get it back.”

Comment: Is it the longest?

Comment: @user253751 2 hours is a pretty long speech in almost any context, not just by a President.

Comment: Lincoln gave a speech of more than three hours while running for President against Douglas. https://www.friendsofthelincolncollection.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/LL_1954-10-11_01.pdf

Comment: @ohwilleke: Thanks, I was considering whether to include campaign speeches (before being elected), but those are probably less well surveyed. (It's also somewhat less clear how further back one could go in their political careers.)

Comment: @ohwilleke: also has a wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln%27s_Peoria_speech